# save a figure with a precise pixels size with savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib

How can I save a plot in a 750x750 px using savefig?

The only useful parameter is DPI, but I don't understand how can I use it for setting a precise size

Answer (score 2):

You set the figure dimension, in inches, when you instantiate the figure and later you specify the dpi so that the dimensions of the saved image are correct.

E.g.,

```
 ...
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
 ...
 fig.savefig('750x750.png', dpi=75) # 75*10 = 750
```

Take into account the dpi of your screen if you want an at least approximate correspondence between the lines' thickness (expressed in typographical points) and the fonts' size with the content of the PNG file.

```
 # screen dpi = 118 pixel / 1inch
 fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(750/118, 750/118))
 ...
 fig.savefig('750x750.png', dpi=118) # 750/118*118 = 750
```

Answer (score 0):

I added plt.tight_layout() before savefig(), and it solved the trimming issue I had. Maybe it will help yours as well.

I also set the figure size at the begining rcParams['figure.figsize'] = 40, 12(you can set your own width and height)